# ASP.net core (пустой проект) не подключается таблица стилей css

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, asp.net, project

Уважаемые разработчики! Столкнулся с непонятной проблемой.
Структура проекта имеет следующий вид: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь подключить style.css к индексу: [image: в Link -> rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/style.css"] 
 что с тильдой,что без тильды... толку ноль...По видео урокам, у преподающего проблем не было, он просто перетянул папку в проект и прописал пути... гуглил, особо не помогло... Прошу помощи у более опытных

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, подскажите на кор платформе не видит это ключевое слово

Comment: Уточните платформу и тип проекта. Сейчас в заголовке и тегах указано ASP.NET. Исправьте.

Comment: @ Alexander Petrov, изменил...еще раз здесь продублирую... проект с нуля, реализую сам с настройками MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил папку wwwroot в проект WebApplication. копировал все из Content в wwwroot.
Путь писал как href="~/style.css". И обязательно добавить в startup в методе  Configure -> app.UseStaticFiles();